# cron job in crontab not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I have added the following entry:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/coddict/myapp-dev/spoolemailsender
```

and the shell that I am trying to execute (the file spoolemailsender) has the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send --env=dev
```

Why isn't this script running every 1 minute? Do I need another command to get this cron job running?

Comment: how do you edit your crontab ?

Comment: @Pierre-LouisLaffont by calling crontab -e

Comment: You can try removing the /1 : `* * * * * /home/coddict/myapp-dev/spoolemailsender`

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put user to execute cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * root /home/coddict/myapp-dev/./spoolemailsender
```

or

```
*/1 * * * * root sh /home/coddict/myapp-dev/spoolemailsender
```

`root` for example.
Assuming `spoolemailsender` is executable script and you don't need to do `./spoolemailsender` or `sh spoolemailsender`

Comment: actually I need to do ./spoolemailsender to run the script.. is that an issue?

Comment: can be, add that to cron job

Comment: what do you mean add that to the cron job?

Comment: `*/1 * * * * root /home/coddict/myapp-dev/./spoolemailsender`, sorry for my simplicity :D